# How to pass array to a setAttribute method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to pass few parameters to `setAttribute()` method
parameters are :

```
var obj = string/this;
var mal_pat_id = "avx";
instruction = "some_instruction";
line = ['a','b','c'];

var newSelect = document.getElementById("dialog_ok_btn_for_mal_pat_conf_yes");

newSelect.setAttribute('onclick', "add("+ obj +","+ mal_pat_id + "," +    instruction + "," + line + ")");
```

parameter **line** is passed as a string, which should be passed as an array.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the **[`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** method instead :

```
newSelect.addEventListener("click", function(){
    add(obj, mal_pat_id, instruction, line);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will this pass the "line" parameter as an array instead of string? As question is asked for this issue.

Comment: String can be simply passed using `add("+ obj +","+ mal_pat_id + "," +    instruction + "," + line + ")`. but i don't think the OP want to pass string then split it ..

Comment: Is that not what you're looking for @Rohan?

Answer (score 1):

Why use set attribute for event listening. Do it directly using `onclick` property like this:

```
newSelect.onclick = function() {
      add(obj, mal_pat_id, instruction, line);
}
```

Or better like this:

```
newSelect.addEventListener("click", function() {
      add(obj, mal_pat_id, instruction, line);
});
```

**Note:** This is not available for all kind of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by **surrounding the array with "[]"** this will make it seem like an array to the function

`newSelect.setAttribute('onclick', "add("+ obj +","+ mal_pat_id + "," +instruction + "," +"[" +line+ "]"+ ")");`

This will set all the array elements of the array line as ['a','b','c'] instead of setting them as 'a','b','c' which will make the function identify them as individual variables